# JPQL query with CURRENT_DATE - 1 does not work

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I am new to `JPA2.0` and `Spring Data JPA` where in I am trying to get the details `where createdDt > Sysdate and createdDt > sysdate-1`. I am not sure if sysdate-1 can be achieved using CURRENT_DATE-1 function, its not working.

Any help as below options doesn't works well? I also tried `YESTERDAY`, this also fails.

**Here I am not looking to developed using PersistanceContext and entity Manager query.**

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM CustMstr e WHERE e.crteDt < CURRENT_DATE AND (DAYS(e.crteDt) > DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) AND e.accActive ='Y'")
List<CustMstr> findByEmailAndAcc();
```

another way

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM CustMstr e WHERE e.crteDt < CURRENT_DATE AND (DAYS(e.crteDt) > CURRENT_DATE - 1) AND e.accActive ='Y'")
List<CustMstr> findByEmailAndAcc();
```

Error below

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'exampleClient': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'CustMstrRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CustMstrRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.XX.XX.repository.CustMstrRepository.findByEmailAndAcc()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:367)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1340)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.XX.XX.app.ExampleMain.main(ExampleMain.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CustMstrRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.XX.XX.repository.CustMstrRepository.findByEmailAndAcc()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:578)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT e FROM CustMstr e WHERE e.crteDt < CURRENT_DATE AND (DAYS(e.crteDt) > DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) AND e.acc_active ='Y']. 
[62, 103] The right expression is not a valid expression.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1616)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
    ... 54 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JPA define `CURRENT_DATE` / `CURRENT_TIME` / `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to be portable way to reference current date / time.

Also, some implementation (not all!) support function like `year` / `month` / `day` / `hour` / `minute` / `second`.

In your code, you use `days`. You can replace it with `day`. But it is a to extract the day of month, not sure it is what you want.

If you want to reference 'yesterday', you can try to use `CURRENT_DATE-1` but it is not necessary portable (some DB will be ok with that, other not).

You can try:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM CustMstr e WHERE e.crteDt between CURRENT_DATE-1 AND  CURRENT_DATE AND e.accActive ='Y'")
List<CustMstr> findByEmailAndAcc();
```

But perhaps you will need to manage this on java side:

on Repository side:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM CustMstr e WHERE e.crteDt between :start and :end AND e.accActive ='Y'")
List<CustMstr> findByEmailAndAcc(Date start, Date end);
```

on service side:

```
List<CustMstr> findByEmailAndAcc(){
    Date start=new Date();
    Date end=new Date(date.getTime()-(24*3600));
    return repository.findByEmailAndAcc(start, end);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. checking .. what if I only need query where created > sysdate - 60 ?

Comment: just try created > CURRENT_DATE-60

Comment: As I noted, it can be dependent on the DB you use and the jpa adapter. For insance, the (current_date-60) is ok with hibernate on postgresql even if I would never use it for instance. I would preffer the 2nd option I Show creating the date in java. This way you have 1 repository findByDate(Date starting);  and you can have many service associated (findLastDay, findLastWeek ... )